# Can Rust handle cyclic data structures without any garbage collector?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to completely avoid a garbage collector and manual deallocation?

Is it possible to implement an interpreter for a language that needs garbage collection (say, Scheme) in Rust, without implementing or using any garbage collector?

Comment: This question is weird. There are three semi related questions. One is in title. And two in body.

Comment: @SanjibPradhan: For a first time, you might want to take a tour of stackoverflow, starting with [How to ask a Good Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd **highly** suggest reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, it's [specifically discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) from asking multiple questions per post. Pretend you were searching the internet for "implement an interpreter for a language that needs garbage collection", would *you* click on a title about "cyclic data structures"? If you received 3 separate answers, one for each question *which one would you accept*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the title question -  Yes, cyclic data structures can be handled without garbage collector.

- http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/04/06/modeling-graphs-in-rust-using-vector-indices/
- http://featherweightmusings.blogspot.com/2015/04/graphs-in-rust.html

For first question. Yes, you can completely avoid garbage collector and manual deallocation *in most cases*. In some you rely on `RC` which is a simple form of garbage collection, or unsafe, which rely on author not missing  a case in which it will be freed.

In some cases it's necessary to write a GC. For example if you are implementing a VM for Javascript, you'll need to develop a GC, because well, that's how JavaScript works. But developing such GC will probably require a large amount of `unsafe` code which again falls on authors back to test, check and prove it works.